# how to get row into django auth_group_permssions model in automated environment

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I am in a CI environment with all code deployment automated.

My django site is using auth_group_permssions .  I need to add a row to this table to create a permssions relation.

Would I populate this value using the forward function of a south data migration script?

If so, how can I access this entity?

With South I have tried the following to access first the auth permission model:

```
    group_permision = orm['auth.Group_Permissions'](group=group, permission=permissi

on)
```

I get the error:

```
KeyError: "The model 'group_permissions' from the app 'auth' is not available in this migration."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
content_type = orm['contenttypes.ContentType'].objects.get(app_label='app', model='model')
    permission, created = orm['auth.Permission'].objects.get_or_create(codename='can_view model',
                                   name='Can view model',
                                   content_type=content_type)

    group, created = orm['auth.Group'].objects.get_or_create(name='my role') 
    group.permissions.add(permission)
```